# How do I show what fields a struct has in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb

I came upon a struct (called `ngx_http_variable_value_t`) in my GDB (debugger) session and I would like to print what fields it has in the console.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use the GDB command `ptype` to print out the definition of a struct or class.

Additionally, use `ptype /o` to print offsets and sizes of all fields in a struct (like pahole).

Comment: This is the right answer. e.g. "(gdb) ptype tm"
"type = struct tm {
    int tm_sec;
    int tm_min;
    int tm_hour;
    int tm_mday;
    int tm_mon;
    int tm_year;
    int tm_wday;
    int tm_yday;
    int tm_isdst;
    long tm_gmtoff;
    const char *tm_zone;
}
"

Comment: What about offsets?

Comment: @ConradMeyer I use this for offsets: `(gdb) p &((struct foo *)0)->member`. Would be nice to have something non-hacky.

Comment: @domen Yeah, that is my hack too.  Also looking for something non-hacky and quicker to type :-).

Comment: What about inner structs? Apparently gdb is not showing them.

Comment: @ConradMeyer Put `macro define offsetof(t, f) &((t *) 0)->f)` into `~/.gdbinit`. Then you can use `(gdb) p offsetof(struct foo, member)`.

Comment: Is there a way to also show fields "inherited" from base classes? I.e. basically all fields/offsets accessible from the given pointer.

Answer (score 69):

If you have debugging symbols built in, you should just be able to print the value: `print variable` or `print *variable` if it's a pointer to a struct.

Comment: And if the variable is a generic pointer, such as a void*, you can cast it to the necessary type, `print ((MY_STRUCT *)variable)`, or to get a specific element of the structure `print ((MY_STRUCT *)variable->my_structure_element`.

Answer (score 30):

**`set print pretty on`**

This option also gives newlines and indentation for `p *my_struct_pointer`.

Which do you prefer:

```
$2 = {path = {mnt = 0xffff8800070ce1a0, dentry = 0xffff880006850600},last = {{{hash = 3537271320, len = 2}, hash_len = 12127205912}, name = 0xffff88000659501c "../b.out"}
```

or:

```
$3 = {
  path = {
    mnt = 0xffff8800070ce1a0, 
    dentry = 0xffff880006850600
  }, 
  last = {
    {
      {
        hash = 3537271320, 
        len = 2
      }, 
      hash_len = 12127205912
    }, 
    name = 0xffff88000659501c "../b.out"
  },
}
```

Comment: The reason I want to have a reputation more than 50 is to upvote an answer like this.
After `set print pretty on` one still need to `p /x ...` for hex format

Answer (score 8):

In addition to using the command line option, you can also use graphical debuggers. I suggest [gdbgui](https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui), but there are quite a few out there.

[image: screenshot]

Disclaimer: I am the developer of gdbgui

Comment: What mi commands are you using to get this information from gdb?

Comment: If you are running gdbgui, you can view all the commands being sent to gdb on behalf of gdbgui. To do this, go to Settings (gear icon) and check the box that says "Print all sent commands in console, including those sent automatically by gdbgui". Otherwise you can inspect the source code https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui.

Answer (score 5):

```
  p *((struct my_struct*) variable)
```

This will help you to print the details of struct in gdb

Answer (score 2):

I've only done this through graphic front ends for gdb. Found this entry in gdb online docs.  Hope it helps.  I believe this will require that the code was created with debugging info included.

ptype [arg] 
ptype accepts the same arguments as whatis, but prints a detailed description of the type, instead of just the name of the type.

[Debugging with GDB:Symbols](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb_17.html#SEC160)

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at the [Data Display Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/).

Answer (score 0):

Assume yout variable is in address X.
You can do the following:

```
set $i1 = (ngx_http_variable_value_t *) = X
print *$i1
print *$i1->name_field
```

Here an example assuming this is my struct and a variable of type strcut internet has been defined within the address 0x804a008:

```
struct internet {
  int priority;
  char *name;
};

(gdb) set $i1 = (struct internet *)0x804a008
(gdb) print *$i1
$17 = {priority = 1, name = 0x804a018 "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEt\227\004\b"}
(gdb) print $i1->name
$18 = 0x804a018 "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEt\227\004\b"
(gdb) print $i1->priority
$19 = 1
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

convert NULL to your type pointer, then use ptype.

```
(gdb) ptype *(struct iovec*)0
    type = struct iovec {
        void *iov_base;
        size_t iov_len;
    }
```

or just

```
ptype {struct iovec}0
```