# Set default TUI layout in .gdbinit?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'd like to have gdb tui open in the regs layout by default. Is there a way to set that in `~/.gdbinit` or some other configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put any gdb command you want in `~/.gdbinit`, including `layout reg`.  This is what I have in mine.

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
layout reg

set print static-members off
set print pretty on
macro define offsetof(t, f) &((t *) 0)->f)  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768620/how-do-i-show-what-fields-a-struct-has-in-gdb#comment78715348_1770422
```

(See also [the bottom of the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for more gdb / asm-debugging tips).

Comment: Oh, weird! I think GDB's parser stops as soon as it has a complete, parsable command in interactive mode, but not when it reads from ~/.gdbinit I had a typo on the command line: layout regs, which works on the command line, but not in the init file. Thank you! That worked!